# Contractible CW-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let Z be a CW complex so that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ every continuous  $f:S^n\rightarrow Z$ is homotopic to a constant map, where $S^n:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ | |x|=1}. Then there is a $g:D^{n+1} \rightarrow Z$ with $g_{|S^n}=f$ where $D^{n+1}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | |x|\leq 1\}$. I am having a hard time comming up with an idea. Thank you

Comment: Being constant is the same as being null-homotopic.  What can you then say about the homotopy groups of your CW complex? Now use Whitehead's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious (but important) realization to make is that the constant map $S^n \to Z$ lifts to a constant map on $D^{n+1} \to Z$. So you have a homotopy from $S^n \to Z$ which has a lift to $D^{n+1}$ at time $t = 0$. Do you know what to do now?